# How can I run code once per second, on the second?

Tags: macos, unix, time

I was writing a command line utility for Mac which should print out status information every second, on the second. Obviously, I don't want to poll a zillion times a second. The only other way I can think of is to get the current time and use select to wait the difference. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any wait you do is guaranteed to wait at least that amount of time, not exactly.  OSX is not a real-time OS -- I don't think there is any way to guarantee anything like that.

If you just want it estimated, then sleeping the difference between now and the time you want (perhaps a little less to give time for the log) will work.

Answer (score 1):

Usually scheduling a method with timer does the trick. However important to remember, the precision is not the best with simple timers.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I have:

```
#import <stdlib.h>
#import <stdio.h>
#import <time.h>
#import <sys/time.h>

#define TIME_LENGTH 9

int main ()
{
    struct timeval now;
    struct timespec wait;

    time_t seconds;
    char str[TIME_LENGTH];

    wait.tv_sec = 0;

    for (;;) {
        gettimeofday(&now, NULL);
        wait.tv_nsec = (1000000 - now.tv_usec) * 1000;
        nanosleep(&wait, NULL);

        seconds = now.tv_sec+1;
        strftime(str, TIME_LENGTH, "%T", localtime(&seconds));
        puts(str);
    }
}
```

It works to "eyeball" precision, which should be good enough. It looks like it's updating in sync with the built-in menubar clock. Evidently, there's a function in `time.h`, `clock_nanosleep`, which can wait until a time rather than wait for a period of time, but this usage is not supported on the mac.